# How do I make a Python client that can consume a .NET (soap) web service?

Tags: python, web-services, soap, webservice-client, suds

I'm trying to make a Python client that can consume a .NET (soap) web service.  I've been looking at the [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) library to do so, as it appears to be frequently recommended. This is what I have so far:

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.transport.https import WindowsHttpAuthenticated

ntlm_transport = WindowsHttpAuthenticated(username='myUserName', password='myPassword')
client = Client('http://server:port/path?wsdl', transport=ntlm_transport)
some_complex_type = client.factory.create('SomeComplexType')

# HOW DO I SET PROPERTIES OF some_complex_type IF THE WSDL DOESN'T DEFINE WHAT IT LOOKS LIKE?

return_value = client.service.MethodThatUsesSomeComplexType(some_complex_type)
```

From the [suds documentation for Complex Arguments](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#ComplexArguments), it appears that typically if you `print client.factory.create('SomeComplexType')` it will output what properties that complex type has (according to the wsdl). In my case, however, if I do: `print some_complex_type`, I get "<empty>", which, I guess, means that the wsdl is missing the definition for `SomeComplexType` (aside from stating that it exists).

Does the maker of the web service that I'm consuming just have things set up incorrectly?  Or is there a special/different way that Microsoft defines types in wsdl, and I just need to configure my suds Client differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that when using the suds library, as in the example above, if a complex type definition is missing from the wsdl, you can send a python dictionary, with the values that the remote service ultimately wants, *in place* of the complex type.

For example, using the example above, instead of doing the following:

```
some_complex_type = client.factory.create('SomeComplexType')
some_complex_type.foo = 'Hello'  # borks is the definition of SomeComplexType is missing from the wsdl
some_complex_type.bar = 'World'
return_value = client.service.MethodThatUsesSomeComplexType(some_complex_type)
```

you can just do the following:

```
some_complex_type = {
    'foo': 'Hello'
    'bar': 'World'
}
return_value = client.service.MethodThatUsesSomeComplexType(some_complex_type)
```

The some_complex_type dictionary can also contain sub-dictioaries and sub-lists of other dictionaries, etc.  The form of the dictionary tree should match the form of the XML that the web service ultimately wants to receive.